# Auto update data from live sheet 1 to sheet 2,sheet3 in every 5 minute

Tags: excel

I want to update from Live data sheet to pair files every 5min time frame for Pair Sheet1,Pair Sheet2 as well as 15 min time frame for Pair Sheet3,Pair Sheet 4  from following formula i just want to know within one file how can i differentiate time frame for multiple stocks.

Sub CopyValues()
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

```
Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(23, 2)

Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(24, 2)

Sheets(3).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(26, 2)

Sheets(3).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(27, 2)
```

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:60:00"), "CopyValues"

End Sub

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime` to trigger a macro on a schedule.

Comment: thanks for reply i am new in vba can you please explain i am using following VBA Sub CopyValues()
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(23, 2)
   
    Sheets(2).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(24, 2)
   
    Sheets(3).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(26, 2)
   
    Sheets(3).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(27, 2)
 
   
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:60:00"), "CopyValues"
 
 
End Sub

Comment: Edit your question if you need to add code: if you put it in a comment no-one can read it